# Getting "document.getElementByClassName is not a function" error in console

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Any ideas how to fix this error: "document.getElementByClassName is not a function"

Code below:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="filter-btn" onclick="myFunction()" data-filter="opd-list-id-<?php echo $item->ID; ?>" style="background:<?php echo $filter_background_color ?>;color:<?php echo $filter_text_color ?> !important;">
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {
var elmnt = document.getElementByClassName("filter-btn");
elmnt.scrollIntoView(); 
}
```

Comment: You're looking for `getElementsByClassName`. Note the "s" on Elements

Comment: @Nick noticed the same thing right away +1

Comment: If you have an error message then the first thing you should do is to search for that error, and check if there is already a question targeting that problem. And if that one does not help you to solve the problem then you should explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replce `getElementByClassName` with `getElementsByClassName`

**note that its plural(`Elements`) with "s" at end and not singular(`Element`)**

the same class can be added to multiple objects hence, selecting by class name returns multiple items, not just one so it uses the plural form `Elements` instead of Element as in case of `getElementById()` as id must be unique and selecting by id will return only one DOM element

and, since the function `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements `elmnt.scrollIntoView()` won't work,
so you need to use the first element of the array as `elmnt[0]`

so you code will be

```js
function myFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("filter-btn");
  elmnt[0].scrollIntoView(); 
}
```

However, I would rather suggest using `getElementById` if you want to select only one element and use as below(first give id `IdGivenToTheAnchoreTag` to anchor tag)

```
function myFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("IdGivenToTheAnchoreTag");
  elmnt.scrollIntoView(); 
}
```

Comment: Got that and changed to Elements, thanks. But now get the following error:Uncaught TypeError: elmnt.scrollIntoView is not a function

Comment: what error? did you forgot to paste?

Comment: Just added the error.

Comment: see my updated answer!

Comment: +1; you would probably want to put the [0] before the end of elmnt's declaration; not before .scrollIntoView();.

Comment: `will return only one DOM` DOM means _Document Object Model_ you mean a DOMElement

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `getElementsByClassName`. Note the "s" on Elements

```
function myFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("filter-btn");
  test.scrollIntoView();  
}
```